# Join a standard FileMaker table with key-value translation pairs

Tags: database-design, relational-database, filemaker

[image: database graph]

A requirement of this database is to have a search function that works across multiple languages. The user will be able to search without knowing which language the text was entered in. And the database needs to support multiple languages without knowing in advance how many there will be.

This question explores a method for creating a field which contains a field with data entered in English from one table and a translation table with multiple other languages.

I have two tables as defined below in FileMaker. The **data** table contains standard fields with each record being a person.

```
data::__ID
data::firstName
data::lastName
```

The **trans** table has field names from the **data** table, the value of the field, the corresponding language, and a foreign key that is used to define a relationship with **data**.

```
trans::fieldName
trans::fieldValue
trans::lang
trans::_fkDataID
```

Here are examples of the table contents:

```
data::(__ID, firstName, lastName)
      (1   , Jane     , Smith)
      (2   , Bob      , Jones)

trans::(fieldName, fieldValue, lang, _fkDataID)
       (firstName, 简        , CN  , 1)
       (firstName, 史密斯    , CN  , 1)
       (firstName, ジェーン  , JP  , 1)
       (firstName, スミス    , JP  , 1)
```

How can I create a field which calculates the following pseudocode?

```
data::__ID & data:firstName & data:lastName & trans:lang <<for first language>>
&
 << trans:firstName
    WHERE 
        trans::lang=‘CN’ AND
        data::__ID == trans::_fkDataID  
 >>
 &
 << repeat for all additional languages in trans >>
```

I would expect the output to look like this:

```
1   Jane   Smith   CN   简   JP   ジェーン
```

I realize that I could write a script to fill in these fields or use auto-enter in the field definition. But these methods would likely have poor performance. Can I  achieve the same results via the relationship graph?

Comment: What would be the purpose of such calculation? The same data can easily be shown in a portal. Keep in mind that FileMaker will not create columns dynamically.

Comment: P.S. There is something about your structure that doesn't quite fit: The `data` table has a fixed number of fields - but the `trans` table is built for any number of fields.

Comment: Added two additional paragraphs at the top describing my motivation. I realize that fields cannot be created dynamically. And the trans table was purposely designed such that it can contain an unlimited number of translations for any one field. Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the purpose. What will the user input (and where)? They could select either first name or  last name, and then the language (all in global fields) - that would be easy to fetch through a relationship, no calculations needed.

Comment: "*And the trans table was purposely designed such that it can contain an unlimited number of translations for any one field.*" Yes, but the data table was **not** designed to contain an unlimited number of fields. So you either have a deficiency in the data table, or an overkill in the trans table.

Comment: The data table already exists. I'm exploring ways to add translations for some of the fields in the data table. But I don't know how many languages I will need.

Comment: To perform a search, I thought that I need an additional field with the first names in all languages. The user would then perform a search by entering his query into a global field. The PatternCount function would check for matches between the global search field and the concatenated field with all languages.

Comment: Perhaps you only need a record for each language, with all (i.e. both) fields included. Hard to advise without knowing the overall purpose.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me there. Please explain this from the point-of-view of the user: what exactly will they enter, and what would they expect to see as he result?

Comment: You mean no extra `trans` table and just create extra records in `data`? How would I then link the multiple records together when they come from the same person?

Comment: The user should enter 'Jane' or '简' and receive the record from `data` with primary key = 1.

Comment: No, I meant one person in the data table would have many records in the trans table - one for every language.

Comment: "*The user should enter 'Jane' or '简'*". If that's what they can enter, then English should be one of the languages - and the English values should be  kept in the trans table with all the rest of them. Note also that Jane could be a last name. That's where this whole thing falls apart.

Comment: P.S. Let me suggest (again): http://fmforums.com or https://community.filemaker.com/community/discussions/ or https://community.filemaker.com/

Comment: I prefer reading stack overflow posts and find the information here useful and reliable. I suppose the other forums are just more often used for FileMaker? Do you know why it's this way?